# Play an audio at a particular time even when the app is closed

Tags: ios, audio, alarm, reminders, ekeventstore

I am creating a prayer reminder app for iPhone. I have a sqlite database from where I am getting the time of prayers for each day. Now, I want to play an alarm or prayer audio(athan) when the prayer time comes(5 times everyday). So, for example, if today the 1st athan time is 5:15 am, whether the app is open or not it should play the alarm. How can I achieve that.

Please note it is different than adding mere events as reminders because firstly, the data is coming from a database, and it is a lot. For a year, it will be (365*5) times. So, I don't know whether adding this much events to event store is feasible or not.

Please suggest me a good option.

Comment: you could schedule local notifications which pops up an alarm even when app is closed but they are limited to 64 only at a time, so you can schedule for like 64/5 .. 13 days . user has to open app within this time for next alarms to be scheduled.

Comment: I don't think that will be a good logic to follow. That will enforce the users to open the app at least once in that period by what if the user for some reason doesn't use the phone for weeks and then when he is back, he must be expecting my app to work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: other is to just add events in native calendar through your app. the calendar app will probably remind them. you will lose the functionality of having control on what to show and sound i guess. should look in the docs